Popping a Modal Dialog when changing the drop down entry in Google Sheets
I am trying to create a script where, when a user selects a specific value in a dropdown, say 'a', and a specific modal dialog is displayed.
I am trying this, but get this error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (Reading 'range')
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Sheet1') return;
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != 'A1') return;  
  if (e.value != 'a') return;
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Practice Criteria");
 var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><h1>Co-creating or Co-designing Core Elements of Activity Design</h1></p><p>1)Activity objectives, results, or interventions determined using a co-creation or co-design process.</p><p>2)Local or regional partners, partner government implementing entities, Innovation Incentive Authority  awardees, and/or stakeholders, including communities, participate in the co-design or co-creation process.</p><p>3)Co-design or Co-creation Process is Documented.</p><p>4)Co-creation or co-design process generated substantiv contributions to Activity Design.</p>");
}


By any chance, did you try to manually run your code? Because onEdit triggers when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet. You may refer on this documentation simple triggers.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
See How do I ask a good question?

Seems to me that widget should be defined before you use it rather than after you use it.

Seems to me that widget should be defined before you use it rather than after you use it.

Also showing a modal dialog requires authoriization and I don't think onEdit performs operations that require authorization.


Cannot red properties of undefined (Reading 'range')

The onEdit(e) function is a simple trigger that is designed to run automatically when you manually edit the spreadsheet. In that context, the event object e is properly populated.
Do not run the code through the ▷ Run button in the script editor. If you do, the event parameter e is not populated, causing the error you mention.
One issue with the code is that it attempts to refer to widget before that variable is declared.
Another issue is that simple triggers run in a restricted context where they cannot use UI methods such as .showModalDialog(). Use an installable trigger instead. You'll need to authorize the code when creating the trigger.
Here's an improved (but untested) version of your code.
function installableOnEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.');
  if (e.value !== 'a'
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'A1'
    || e.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet1') {
    return;
  }
  const widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p><h1>Co-creating or Co-designing Core Elements of Activity Design</h1></p><p>1)Activity objectives, results, or interventions determined using a co-creation or co-design process.</p><p>2)Local or regional partners, partner government implementing entities, Innovation Incentive Authority  awardees, and/or stakeholders, including communities, participate in the co-design or co-creation process.</p><p>3)Co-design or Co-creation Process is Documented.</p><p>4)Co-creation or co-design process generated substantive contributions to Activity Design.</p>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, 'Practice Criteria');
}


See Apps Script at Stack Overflow. Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

Welcome to stackoverflow! If this resolves your question, please click the check mark (✓) on the left to accept the answer and consider upvoting it. This helps others in the community who might have similar questions know that this solution works.
